# How to check if char that was read from file is "/n"?

Tags: c#, string

Hi I `m trying to grep through file and count number of lines, maximum number of spaces per line, and longest line.

How I can determine "/n" character if i iterate char by char trough given file?

Thanks a lot.

Here is my code that I used for this:

```
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(p_FileName))
     {

  char currentChar;
  int current_length=0,current_MaximumSpaces=0;
    p_LongestLine=0;
    p_NumOfLines=0;
    p_MaximumSpaces=0;
    while (!sr.EndOfStream){
        currentChar=Convert.ToChar(sr.Read());
        current_length++;
        if(Char.IsWhiteSpace(currentChar) || currentChar==null){
            current_MaximumSpaces++;
        }
        if(currentChar == '\n'){
            p_NumOfLines++;
        }
        if(current_length>p_LongestLine){
            p_LongestLine=current_length;
        }
        if(current_MaximumSpaces>p_MaximumSpaces){
            p_MaximumSpaces=current_MaximumSpaces;
        }
        current_length=0;
        current_MaximumSpaces=0;
    }
    sr.Close();
}
```

Comment: The slash goes the other way, and you need single quotes instead of double quotes :)

Comment: Please provide code of how you are currently trying to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to go character by character: for your purposes, going line-by-line is sufficient, and you get the .NET to deal with system-dependent line breaks for you as an added bonus.

```
int maxLen = -1, maxSpaces = -1;
foreach ( var line in File.ReadLines("c:\\data\\myfile.txt")) {
    maxLen = Math.Max(maxLen, line.Length);
    maxSpaces = Math.Max(maxSpaces, line.Count(c => c == ' '));
}
```

**EDIT**: Your program does not work because of an error unrelated to you checking the `'\n'`: you are zeroing out the `current_length` and `current_MaximumSpaces` after each character, instead of clearing them only when you see a newline character.

Comment: Exactly. `current_length` should be zeroed out in the branch where the newline is found. And I don't like comparing a char to `null`, but that could be just me.

Answer (score 5):

```
if(currentChar == '\n')
    count++;
```

Comment: I used this... It doesn't work!
There is no way to do this like we check the space char: char.IsSpace()

Comment: @AlexanderBerdichevsky:  Did you use the backslash instead of forwand slash?

Comment: @AlexanderBerdichevsky:  Please show the code you tried. Then it is easier to find the error.

Comment: @AlexanderBerdichevsky `char.isSpace()` does not exactly check if the operand is "the space char"; it returns true for line feeds as well...

Comment: It may be helpful to include a snippet of your parsing code and the file being parsed.  The first question that I'd ask - are you sure that the lines in your file are terminated with the line feed character?

Answer (score 0):

Try comparing to [`Environment.NewLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx)

```
bool is_newline = currentChar.ToString().Equals(Environment.NewLine);
```

I'm guessing that you newline is actually `\r\n` (non Unix) ending.  You'll need to keep track of the previous/current char's and look for either `\r\n` or `Environment.NewLine`.

Comment: You do realise that `Environment.NewLine` is a string consisting of two characters, so it will never match a single character?

Comment: @MrLister - You do realise it depends on the platform?

Comment: All the more reason not to use it!

Comment: @MrLister - So you dont want to use something that is flexible enough to detect the newline character?

Comment: I'm saying that your code DOES NOT WORK under Windows. It compares the string `"\n"` to the string `"\r\n"`, which will return false.